# UISegmentedControl custom images for each segment

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to customize a UISegmentedControl to use a custom image for each segment.  I've done a lot of searching, but haven't had any luck with the solutions I've tried so far.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702599/uisegmentedcontrol-custom-image-for-segment) is the most recent post I can find, which is still fairly out of date now, and seems pretty hacky yet.  Are there any better or more recent guides on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to change the image for the content or the background?

Comment: The content.  By default, the UISegmentedControl has the light gray colored segments with the outside segments having rounded corners and a transparent background.  I have a segmented control with 3 segments, and I need to make the left segment yellow, the middle green, and the right red.  Each segment image has a custom gradient.

Comment: Check this tutorial. This is the max you can achieve. http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `UISegmentedControl` doesn’t make it easy to set separate background images for each segment separately. If your control is always a known width, you might be able to make a full-size background image with the three segments drawn in, like this: `(yellow][green][red)` (where parentheses represent rounded corners), and then use `-[UISegmentedControl setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:]` to set your image.

However, that solution isn’t very flexible if you want to resize the control later. You might be better off faking it with three adjacent `UIButton`s, or even subclassing `UIControl` to make a custom segmented control which can have a separate image for each segment.